# How does one install Python 3.7 in HPC without root access on Linux?

Tags: python, ssl, makefile, hpc

I followed this link i found on github, (link : https://github.com/ranzan998/hpc_python) and managed to install all required libraries, made necessary changes to the  .bashrc. I crossed checked all the paths and they seem fine. I’m currently stuck with an SSL error and I’m not sure how to proceed forward.

This is the link to the installation in detail : https://github.com/ranzan998/hpc_python/blob/main/steps_detailed.txt

Here’s a snippet of the error shown in the terminal:

libpython3.7m.a(_ssl.o): In function `_ssl__SSLContext_impl': /home/path/python/libraries/Python_374/./Modules/_ssl.c:3130: undefined reference to` SSL_CTX_get0_param'
/home/path/python/libraries/Python_374/./Modules/_ssl.c:3136: undefined reference to `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags' /home/path/python/libraries/Python_374/./Modules/_ssl.c:2986: undefined reference to` TLSv1_1_method'
/home/path/python/libraries/Python_374/./Modules/_ssl.c:2988: undefined reference to `TLSv1_2_method'

‘undefined reference to’ seems to be the crux of the error. Can anybody help?